# How to write to csv in python with exceptions in the middle

Tags: python, csv, exception

I am trying to parse directories and get some values from certain files.
I donot have access to all files.
I want to write a script which will write the results from the files that I can read and simply log the ones I donot have access to.
When I parse directories of which I have access to all the files, then my csv is perfect but if even one exception is thrown(which i handle using try except), my file returns empty.

```
def read_files_extract_stuff_and_write_to_csv(f, sasfile, writer):
   with SAS7BDAT(sasfile) as fsas:
       for col in fsas.columns:
           if(col.name == 'blah'):
               writer.writerow([sasfile, len(fasas.columns)])  

f = open(file.csv, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for sasfile in directory
   try:
      read_files_extract_stuff_and_write_to_csv(f, sasfile, writer)
   except Exception as ex:
      print(ex)
f.close()
```

My main exception is I donot have access to read those files. I just want to simply skip them but when I do, its an empty csv.

Exception :
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '//filepath/filename'

Comment: Your code looks good, but without seeing the part you replaced with a comment it is hard to say where your problem lies.

Comment: So, what exception do you get raised? Is it IOError or some other exception?

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'filepath/filename'

Comment: Your code won't run because you use `for file in directory` but actually used `sasfile`. You tried to change your original code, but I suspect the error lies in the part that you changed.

Comment: Yes, my bad, that was just a typo. Can't copy paste. This is a highly condensed logic part. The code is working fine if I have access to all files in the dir. But if there is 1 file that I donot have access to, then the entire csv is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the Exception and continue, for example:

```
try:
    read_files_extract_stuff_and_write_to_csv(f, sasfile, writer)
except PermissionError:
    continue
```